# Function does not appear in Azure Portal

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-durable-functions

I have deployed the Python code for Azure Functions from VScode.

When I run the code in Vscode, I was able to confirm that it works successfully, but when
I try to open the function app from the Azure Portal, the URL and other information is not displayed.

I was able to run it in Vscode so I don't know what I need to fix, etc.
I have included the code we are using below.

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import Logger
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only

class AzureBlobLogger(Logger):
    def __init__(self, container_name, blob_name_prefix, connection_string):
        super().__init__()
        self.container_name = container_name
        self.blob_name_prefix = blob_name_prefix
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        if not self.container_client.exists():
            self.container_client.create_container()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return 'AzureBlobLogger'

    @property
    def version(self):
        return '0.0.1'

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_metrics(self, metrics, step):
        blob_name = f"{self.blob_name_prefix}_step_{step}.csv"
        blob_client = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=self.container_name, blob=blob_name)
        csv_content = ",".join([f"{k},{v}" for k, v in metrics.items()])
        blob_client.upload_blob(csv_content, overwrite=True)

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_hyperparams(self, params):
        # Implement if needed
        pass

class Net(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(588, 10) 

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.conv(x)
        h = F.relu(h)
        h = self.bn(h)
        h = F.max_pool2d(h, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        h = h.view(-1, 588)
        h = self.fc(h)
        return h
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        train_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('train_acc', train_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        val_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('val_acc', val_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        test_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('test_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('test_acc', test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.01) 
        return optimizer

app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("image", "")
    return result

### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/test.txt", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def image(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):

    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_val = datasets.MNIST('./', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test = datasets.MNIST('./', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

    n_train,n_val = 50000, 10000
    torch.manual_seed(0)
    train, val = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_val, [n_train, n_val])

    batch_size = 256
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=batch_size)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size)

    net = Net()
    azure_logger = AzureBlobLogger(
        container_name="newblob",
        blob_name_prefix="log",
        connection_string="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=..."
    )
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, deterministic=True, logger=azure_logger)
    trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
    results = trainer.test(dataloaders=test_loader)
    return str(results)
```

The picture shows the Azure Portal in Japanese. In the yellow area of the image, a group of functions that should normally be displayed are not shown.

[image]

Comment: provide the output log it shows the error of the deployment or your code seems to be not complete as it is giving many modules not found errors when trying with the same code.

Comment: If it is blob trigger, where are the code lines like `@app.blob_trigger(arg_name, path, connection)` and `def blob_trigger(myblob:func.InputStream)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to Deploy the Function, Make use of Function Core tool command and your Visual Studio Azure Functions extension with proper settings in the Configuration tab of Azure Function app like below:-

***Approach 1:-***

**Function Core tools command:-**

*Have Azure Functions Core tools installed as a pre-requisite.*

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription "Subscription-Name"
func azure functionapp publish functionName
```

***Approach 2:-***

Another option is to directly deploy it from the ***VS Code Azure Functions Extension*** like below:-

[image]

Wait for some time after deployment and Refresh the Azure Function App browser page for the Functions to populate. Retry the Deployment if it fails. As due to the transient issue the Function might not be visible.

**Output:-**

[image]

Make sure you have below Application Settings in the Configuration section like below:-

```json
[
  {
    "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
    "value": "InstrumentationKey=c11e7d7d-cfb0-43cb-873c-79e542bcf79c;IngestionEndpoint=https://australiaeast-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiaeast.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags",
    "value": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconrg57b41c;AccountKey=xxxxxxxE/U6qIUy25/sJnT23e2L+AStNiYl2g==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "BUILD_FLAGS",
    "value": "UseExpressBuild",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "python",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
    "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconrg57b41c;AccountKey=xxxxxxx/U6qIUy25/sJnT23e2L+AStNiYl2g==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "valleyfunc890b912",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "XDG_CACHE_HOME",
    "value": "/tmp/.cache",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

[image]

**My Function Code:-**

```py
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import Logger
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only

class AzureBlobLogger(Logger):
    def __init__(self, container_name, blob_name_prefix, connection_string):
        super().__init__()
        self.container_name = container_name
        self.blob_name_prefix = blob_name_prefix
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        self.container_client = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        if not self.container_client.exists():
            self.container_client.create_container()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return 'AzureBlobLogger'

    @property
    def version(self):
        return '0.0.1'

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_metrics(self, metrics, step):
        blob_name = f"{self.blob_name_prefix}_step_{step}.csv"
        blob_client = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=self.container_name, blob=blob_name)
        csv_content = ",".join([f"{k},{v}" for k, v in metrics.items()])
        blob_client.upload_blob(csv_content, overwrite=True)

    @rank_zero_only
    def log_hyperparams(self, params):
        # Implement if needed
        pass

class Net(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(588, 10) 

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.conv(x)
        h = F.relu(h)
        h = self.bn(h)
        h = F.max_pool2d(h, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        h = h.view(-1, 588)
        h = self.fc(h)
        return h
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        train_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('train_acc', train_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        val_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('val_acc', val_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        test_acc = accuracy(y.argmax(dim=-1), t, task='multiclass', num_classes=10, top_k=1)
        self.log('test_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('test_acc', test_acc, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss
    
    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.01) 
        return optimizer

app  =  df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)  
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async  def  client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id  =  await  client.start_new("orchestrator", None, {})
    await  client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)

### orchestrator function ###
@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext) -> str:
    result = yield context.call_activity("image", "")
    return result

### activity function ###
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="newblob/test.txt", connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="blank")
def image(blank: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):

    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_val = datasets.MNIST('./', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    test = datasets.MNIST('./', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)

    n_train,n_val = 50000, 10000
    torch.manual_seed(0)
    train, val = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_val, [n_train, n_val])

    batch_size = 256
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=batch_size)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size)

    net = Net()
    azure_logger = AzureBlobLogger(
        container_name="newblob",
        blob_name_prefix="log",
        connection_string="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=siliconrg57b41c;AccountKey=xxxxxxxe2L+AStNiYl2g==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    )
    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=3, deterministic=True, logger=azure_logger)
    trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
    results = trainer.test(dataloaders=test_loader)
    return str(results)
```